# Unable to create repository on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Listing works fine:

```
$ gcloud source repos list  --project=<myproj>
REPO_NAME        PROJECT_ID  URL
backend-django   <myproj>  https://source.developers.google.com/p/<myproj>/r/backend-django
crawler-scripts  <myproj>  https://source.developers.google.com/p/<myproj>/r/crawler-scripts
webapp           <myproj>  https://source.developers.google.com/p/<myproj>/r/webapp
```

But creating a new repo fails:

```
$ gcloud source repos create serve  --project=<myproj>
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.create) ResponseError: status=[INTERNAL], code=[500], message=[INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.].
```

The worst part is - the error response `"Internal error encountered."` does not help at all.

Things I have done so far:

- Double checked my permissions. I happen to be the `owner` with `write` privileges.
- Checked with billing. They confirmed there is no payment-related issue and my account is in good standing.
- Tried using the GUI but clicking the "Create" button brings up the loading spinner briefly, and then does nothing.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a Google Cloud issue. They fixed it after 5 months of waiting but by then I moved my repos to another provider. It is extremely disappointing such things are happening on production. If you're facing similar issues, it's probably not worth your time and effort to troubleshoot as it could be an infrastructure issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues that occur on GCP that are related to our internal systems throwing error messages, it would be suggested to create a Issue Tracker to report these findings to have them looked over by the internal engineering team for revision and resolution:

https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: This question is almost 3 years old...